# How to configure ZeroRPC and timeouts

Tags: python, node.js, zeromq, zerorpc

I'm trying to do some simple load-testing with a ZeroRPC python server and node.js client. What I notice is that if the request takes longer than 10 seconds, I get no data back. I tried to configure no heartbeat in the python code:

```
s = zerorpc.Server(Test(), heartbeat=None)
```

as well as trying to configure the node.js client:

```
new zerorpc.Client({ timeout: 60, heartbeatInterval: 60000 }),
```

but still see the same behavior.

How can I get requests taking longer than 10 seconds to return results?

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution to this? I am having the same issue now.

Answer (score 0):

The last available release of zerorpc-node (0.9.3) use an harcoded HEARBEAT timeout.

As you can see in https://github.com/dotcloud/zerorpc-node/blob/0.9.3/lib/channel.js :

```
//Heartbeat rate in milliseconds
var HEARTBEAT = 5000;
...
//Resets the heartbeat expiration time
Channel.prototype._resetHeartbeat = function() {
    this._heartbeatExpirationTime = util.curTime() + HEARTBEAT * 2;
};
```

However the latest master release implement the hearbeatInterval option as you try to specify in the client contructor.

Then your code works installing the lastest master with the command

```
npm install git+https://github.com/dotcloud/zerorpc-node.git
```

Or wait for a new release ....

Answer (score 0):

for latest [js zerorpc](https://github.com/0rpc/zerorpc-node) version `v0.9.8`:

```
# npm list zerorpc
xxx/electron-python-example
└── zerorpc@0.9.8
```

and latest [python zerorpc](https://github.com/0rpc/zerorpc-python) version `v0.6.3`

```
# pip show zerorpc             
Name: zerorpc
Version: 0.6.3
Summary: zerorpc is a flexible RPC based on zeromq.
Home-page: https://github.com/0rpc/zerorpc-python
Author: François-Xavier Bourlet <bombela+zerorpc@gmail.com>.
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: MIT
Location: xxx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: msgpack, future, pyzmq, gevent
Required-by:
```

which provide you already said the `heartbeatInterval`.

so my here using code `electron-python-example/renderer.js`:

```
const constLargeEnoughHeartbeat = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 12 // 1 Year
clientOptions = {
  "heartbeatInterval": constLargeEnoughHeartbeat,
}
let client = new zerorpc.Client(clientOptions)
```

can implement you expected: large enough to 1 year heartbeat -> so longer than 10s, js and python still running, no more error

- js: `invoke startSaver: error=Error: Lost remote after 10000ms`
- python: `zerorpc.exceptions.LostRemote: Lost remote after 10s heartbeat`