# Python/Node ZeroRPC heartbeat error

Tags: python, node.js, zeromq, zerorpc

Im trying to run the Python server/node.js client HelloWorld example from the ZeroRPC [website](http://zerorpc.dotcloud.com/).  All the revelant libraries seemed to have been installed correctly, but when running the example I get the error:

```
{ name: 'HeartbeatError',
  message: 'Lost remote after 10000ms',
  traceback: '' }
```

Has anyone seen this?

Comment: There is an answer in a similar question [How to configure ZeroRPC and timeouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203973/how-to-configure-zerorpc-and-timeouts)

Comment: please refer my answer for another post [python - How to configure ZeroRPC and timeouts - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203973/how-to-configure-zerorpc-and-timeouts)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using "zerorpc": "^0.9.3"
I come across with the same issue when I was running a time-consuming python code. The way to solve the issue is that you need to modify the library code of zerorpc:
node_modules -> zerorpc -> lib -> channel.js
Change the cooresponding method to

```
//Runs the heartbeat on this channel
Channel.prototype._runHeartbeat = function() {
    var self = this;

    return setInterval(function() {
        if(util.curTime() > self._heartbeatExpirationTime) {
            //If we haven't received a response in 2 * heartbeat rate, send an
            //error
//            self.emit("heartbeat-error", "Lost remote after " + (HEARTBEAT * 2) + "ms");
//            self.close();
        }

        //Heartbeat on the channel
        try {
            var event = events.create(self._envelope, self._createHeader(), "_zpc_hb", [0]);
            self._socket.send(event);
        } catch(e) {
            console.error("Error occurred while sending heartbeat:", e);
        }
    }, HEARTBEAT);
};
```

In the latest code from github: https://github.com/dotcloud/zerorpc-node
they have solved this issue.

Comment: Is disabling heartbeat a recommended practice in this case ?  I experience the same issue with Python processes longer that 10s. IMO, heartbeat shouldn't be frozen when a Python process is ongoing!

Comment: This is a bug in the old code, they should have let developer to set the heartbeat.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, use gevent.sleep to let zerorpc enough time to process waiting messages, including heartbeat.